# Improve engine sound of Mazda RX-8

Tags: mazda, exhaust

I would like my 2006 Mazda RX-8 Shinka to be a little louder. I just don't know where to start though. The engine has such a nice sound, but I can't really hear it. I don't want it to be so loud that it annoys the neighbors but a little more sound would be nice. It has the stock exhaust and intake right now. I don't think it's allowed to remove the cat here in Arizona. I also don't want anything that might make the car run hotter. I'm aware that answers will mostly be limited to exhaust and intake mods, but I just don't know where to start!

You can hear the sound of the car in the video I made...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnzaAj5T_kI (go to 7:30 for the driving test)

Comment: Have you tried removing sound insulation from the cockpit and trunk areas? You will hear more without annoying those around you. However, you'll definitely annoy your passengers so choose your spouse carefully....

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. I don't need to hear the woman in the passenger seat :)

Answer (score 2):

We are not going to be able to tell you what you like and don't like in an exhaust note. I may like something, which may sound too raspy or too loud or too (insert here) to you. What you need to do is go to YouTube and do a search for "[Mazda RX8 Exhaust Sound](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mazda+rx8+exhaust+sound)" ... in fact if you click the link I provided, it will take you there. Take a listen to the different exhaust notes, figure out which one you like, and go someplace and purchase it. You would be looking for a "cat-back". Arizona does have smog laws which would not permit you to remove your cats, unless you do something nefarious like get your PCM tuned where the CEL doesn't come on. Aftermarket cat back systems are made to fit so well, a regular person can change out the stock exhaust system to the aftermarket one with regular hand tools (basic socket set, jack, jack stands, and possibly some way to cut the old exhaust off). It's something you can do without taking it to a shop. The car would not need to have the computer tuned after putting it on.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't think of Youtube, which is embarassing because I'm a YoutubeManiac and make that suggestion to other folks all the time. But, are you saying that there's no way to make it a little louder without completely changing the character of the sound? Because, I like it the way it is, just want it a little louder.

Comment: This goes back to preference. I'm sure if you do an exhaustive (pun intended) search on YouTube, you can come up with something which will suit what you want. Other than that, punch some holes in your exhaust? J/K.

Answer (score 0):

Finally someone mentions rotary engines!

Installing a huge freeflow exhaust and the biggest rear silencer box you can fit will give you a nice deep growl. Remember to not go too big on the pipe because that actually robs performance (for the same reason chimneys are long and slender and not short and fat). A short ram intake would also improve the sound. Take note that there is a thing called a sports cat (a cool-sounding name for a high-flow catalytic converter) which will sound better, but still remain legal). Finally, if you feel like spending lots of money, have the engine bridge-ported. It improves the airflow into the engine, but also gives it a nice angry sound.

All this being said, [this video has the prettiest engine sound IN THE WORLD](http://youtu.be/oEOHn7rspsk)(said in Jeremy Clarkson's voice):

Comment: Juann ... there is ***a lot*** of opinion laced in your answer. You should really refrain from giving answers like because it really is not inline with the SE model. You believe the sound emitted by your preference of exhaust is just awesome, but to me it may sound just like a tin can. Very subjective; very opinionated.

Comment: But, it's a good answer because it helps me figure out where to start. That's the point here, I'm not asking folks to choose for me, just help get started.